# Multiply matrices with Loop in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix-multiplication, matrix-inverse

I have a matrix "eps" with 2 rows and n columns. I also have a matrix B with 2 rows and 2 columns. I want to multiply the inverse of B with each column of "eps" to acquire n new matrices dimension 2x1. Then I transpose those n new matrices for dimension 1x2 and fill them in matrix U which has 2 columns and n rows.

But my code below is wrong with the message "Error: unexpected symbol in "for i"" from R. Could you please help me? Thanks a lot!

```
for i in 1:nrow(U){U[i,] <- t(solve(B)%*%eps[,i])}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`U <- t(solve(B, eps))` and done!

Regarding the error: `for (i in 1:nrow(U))` please read `?Control`.

Comment: `?for` doesnt exist, does it?

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi: i thought i already did it with your answer too :)